# Windows cannot access - Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, file-sharing, unc

I've a local share in my laptop

\Siva\archive and connected with a wifi network at the moment

Then I try to access, it just comes back with

This error

[image: Error Image]

As the OS is latest windows 10, it does have a feature mobile hotspot so turned it on and tried again to access the share and it opens fine without any issues

i have tried disabling the firewall and checked the proxies as well Don't have any antivirus though

one more thing i disconnected all networks from the laptop and tried again and it's also a success >> opens fine

only thing is that when i connect the wifi i couldn't access my local share

Comment: What device are you trying to connect from when using wireless? Do you have wireless isolation turned on in your router?

Comment: the share is in the same laptop from where i'm trying